# 'Have' vs 'Having' : Whats different?

Tags: word-meaning, difference, word-difference

I'm so confused with that two words, It's different each others? Or their have a special rules on use that words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have is a [stative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stative_verb).

These are verbs such as has/have, be/am/is/are, like, hate, own, think.
They have different meanings depending on if they are in simple or continuous forms.

> I **have** a brother.

This describes a state of being and not necessarily an "action".

> I'm **having** difficulty, please wait.

This describes an actual action that is happening now.